# Prove that every element of a group G can be represented as $g = x^{-1}(xT)$ for some x $\in$ G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**Let G be a finite group and T be an automorphism on G with the property that T(x) = x for $ \ \ $ x $\in$ G iff x = e.**

- Prove that every element of G can be represented as $g = x^{-1}(xT)$.
- Suppose further that $T^2 = I$ . Then G must be abelian .

I have tried :

Since G is finie . Then G = $\{e,a_1,a_2,..........,a_n \}$ and T be an automorphism any $a_j \in$ G , then $\exists \ \ a_i$ such that T($a_i) = a_j$ $\Rightarrow a_i^{-1}T(a_i) =     a_i^{-1}a_j$. Further how to solve

Comment: Is $xT$ the same thing as $T(x)$?

Comment: Most probably yes, @GerryMyerson. Vintage algebraists notation, pretty widespread until some 50-60 years ago.

Comment: @Don, did vintage algebraists use both notations within the statement of a single problem?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, @GerryMyerson...hehe. Perhaps *very vintage* ones do.

Comment: As an undergraduate (that's still less than 50 years ago I think), I used to get into trouble for writing $fg(x)$ meaning $g(f(x))$ (so I was effectively confusing the two notations).

Comment: @DerekHolt, risking the shame to be repeating myself: I studied with prof. S. Amitsur in the Hebrew University, and he was a vehement algebraist *also* in his notation. His great book "Algebra" (sorry, only in hebrew...) uses the vintage notation and we all had to get used to it. One thing that results from this notation is that the matrix corresponding to a lin. transformation wrt some basis is **not the transpose** of the resulting linear system's coefficients matrix, as usual now, but directly that matrix. Thus for us it was an $\;n\times m\;$ matrix, whereas now it's a $\;m\times n\;$ one

Comment: @DonAntonio What is "the resulting system's coefficients matrix"? I'm not familiar with that terminology.

Comment: @DanielFischer: choose one basis D in the domain, and one basis I in the image. Apply the lin. trans. to each element of D and write the result as a lin. combination of I. Look at the coefficients you get. With the $\;Tx\;$ notation now, we *must* take this coefficients matrix's transpose and that is the matrix corresponding to the lin. t. wrt. D, I.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. I'm not sure I understand what you mean though. Writing $k_B(v)$ for the coefficient $d$-tuple of the vector $v$ with respect to the basis $B$ and $M_B^A(f)$ for the matrix of $f$ wrt the bases $A$ and $B$, we have $$k_I(Tx) = M_I^D(T)\cdot k_D(x).$$ The $i$-th column of $M_I^D(T)$ consists of the coefficients of the $i$-th vector of the basis $D$. Have you maybe learned to write the coefficients as the rows of the "resulting system's coefficients matrix", or do I still not see what that is?

Comment: Exactly my point, @DanielFischer (though I'm not sure what that $\;k_i\,,\,k_D\;$ thingy is): $\;i$-th column $\;\rightarrow\;$ $\;i$-th vector's coefficients, which means taking the transpose of the system. In vintage algebraists notation, $\;i$-th **row** $\;\rightarrow\;$ $\;i$-th vector's coefficients

Comment: The computer algebra systems GAP and Magma, which are used a lot by algebraists  both still use this transposed notation for matrices (so they act by multiplying row vectors on the right by a matrix), but It causes a lot of confusion for new users.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I think we're confusing here stuff and I can't see how and where to clear this up: the transposed notation is used *now*, where the action of a function in general is to the left of the argument, so that GAP and MAGMA thing you talk about *should* be clear to all nowadays students. In order to apply a function (matrix) *to the right* of the argument/vector one *must* then take the untransposed matrix...

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't follow :( For me, there's no transpose in sight. $$\begin{matrix} V & \xrightarrow{T} & W\\ \downarrow &&\downarrow\\ K^n & \xrightarrow{x\mapsto A\cdot x} & K^m \end{matrix}$$ where the vertical arrows are the coordinate isomorphisms, and $A$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the two bases, which has the coordinates of the $T(v_i)$ in the columns.

Answer (score 2):

$\;\forall\,x,y\in G\;$ :

$$x^{-1}(xT)=y^{-1}(yT)\implies yx^{-1}=yT(xT)^{-1}=(yx^{-1})T\stackrel{\text{given}}\iff yx^{-1}=1\iff x=y$$

Now, for all $\;x\in G\;\;\exists\,g_x,\in G\;$ s.t.$\;x=g_x^{-1}(g_xT)\iff g_xx=g_xT\;$ , so if $\;T^2=I\;$ we get:

$$\begin{cases}(g_xx)T=g_xT^2=g_x\\{}\\xT=g_x^{-1}T(g_xT^2)=(g_xT)^{-1}g_x\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;,\;\;\text{and from here:}$$

$${}$$

$$(xy)^{-1}=\left(g_x^{-1}(g_xT)g_y^{-1}(g_yT)\right)^{-1}=(g_yT)^{-1}g_y(g_xT)^{-1}g_x=yTxT=$$

$$=(yx)T=(g_{yx}T)^{-1}g_{yx}=\left(g_{yx}^{-1}(g_{yx}T)\right)^{-1}=(yx)^{-1}$$

Since

$$xy=\begin{cases}g_x^{-1}(g_xT)g_y^{-1}(g_yT)\\{}\\g_{xy}^{-1}(g_{xy}T)\end{cases}\;$$

I'm almost sure the above can be somewhat shortened...but not much, if my memory serves me well.